# SQL stored proc - Trying to differentiate by date and if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, if-statement, datediff

I have a list of exchange rates categorised by currency, that I need to somehow post the difference of value on.

For example:

- GBP to USD | date of capture: 23/02/12 | value: 5
- GBP to USD | date of capture: 22/02/12 | value: 3
- GBP to USD | date of capture:
  21/02/12 | value: 3

What I want to happen is; when the query is run, it automatically works out the latest date that was take, compare this when the previous date taken, and post back a value to say if this has been increase i.e. if increase then "^", if decrease "v", if same "<->".

My current query can pull out the latest date taken, but I still need to do a sub query to pull out the second latest date and value, and then post an if statement.

Am I barking up the right tree with my method?

Here is my code.

```
SELECT
distinct t.source_currency_code, t.target_currency_code,
t.entry_no as entry_no,
'(' + t.source_currency_code + ') '  + s.currency_name as source_currency_name, 
'(' + t.target_currency_code + ') '  + x.currency_name as target_currency_name,
t.value_amount as value_amount,
t.uplift_percent as uplift,
t.date_loaded as date_loaded

from texchange_rate t, tcurrency s, tcurrency x

where 
s.currency_code = t.source_currency_code and 
x.currency_code = t.target_currency_code and
t.date_loaded in 
      (
          SELECT max(date_loaded) from texchange_rate tt
          where t.source_currency_code = tt.source_currency_code 
          and t.target_currency_code = tt.target_currency_code
      )

order by source_currency_code, target_currency_code


SELECT
distinct t.source_currency_code, t.target_currency_code,
t.entry_no as entry_no,
'(' + t.source_currency_code + ') '  + s.currency_name as source_currency_name, 
'(' + t.target_currency_code + ') '  + x.currency_name as target_currency_name,
t.value_amount as value_amount,
t.uplift_percent as uplift,
t.date_loaded as date_loaded2

from texchange_rate t, tcurrency s, tcurrency x

where 
s.currency_code = t.source_currency_code and 
x.currency_code = t.target_currency_code and
t.date_loaded in 
       (
          SELECT max(date_loaded) from texchange_rate tt
          where t.source_currency_code = tt.source_currency_code
          and t.target_currency_code = tt.target_currency_code
      )
    and
      t.value_amount in 
      (
          SELECT value_amount from texchange_rate tt
          where DATEDIFF(day, date_loaded, getdate()) < date_loaded
            and t.source_currency_code = tt.source_currency_code
            and t.target_currency_code = tt.target_currency_code
      )

order by source_currency_code, target_currency_code
```

Some sample data:

```
4366    GBP USD 15986   23/01/2012 13:42:02
4337    GBP USD 15600   17/10/2011 12:37:58
4312    GBP USD 15500   22/08/2011 14:00:01
4287    GBP USD 15500   21/08/2011 14:00:01
```

Comment: Briefly, yes. You'll want to get the latest value and join back to the same source where max date != the date of the latest value. Or, you could recursive find all pairs of differences and take the last one. It would be helpful to have some sample data from each table, or at least a definition of each.

Comment: Hmm okay. I've edited in some sample data in my initial post, cause I can't do it clearly in the reply box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could try a variation on the accepted answer to your previous question:

```
select source_currency_code, 
       target_currency_code,
       max(source_currency_name) source_currency_name, 
       max(target_currency_name) target_currency_name,
       max(case when rn = 1 then value_amount end) value_amount,
       max(case when rn = 1 then uplift end) uplift,
       max(case when rn = 1 then date_loaded end) date_loaded,
       case sign(max(case when rn = 1 then value_amount end) - 
                 max(case when rn = 2 then value_amount end))
           when 1 then '^'
           when 0 then '<->'
           when -1 then 'v'
       end change_over_previous
from 
(select t.source_currency_code, 
        t.target_currency_code,
        '('+t.source_currency_code+') '  + s.currency_name as source_currency_name, 
        '('+t.target_currency_code+') '  + x.currency_name as target_currency_name,
        t.value_amount as value_amount,
        t.uplift_percent as uplift,
        t.date_loaded as date_loaded,
        rank() over (partition by t.source_currency_code, 
                                  t.target_currency_code 
                     order by t.date_loaded desc) rn
 from texchange_rate t
 join tcurrency s on s.currency_code = t.source_currency_code 
 join tcurrency x on x.currency_code = t.target_currency_code) v
where rn in (1, 2)
group by source_currency_code, target_currency_code
order by source_currency_code, target_currency_code
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. How are you so good at this?!

I had reverted back to your method, but my solution that I was attempting was going to be posting the results into a new table with separate fields and then and if statement working out the result difference.

Thanks again, it's extremely appreciated!

Comment: Shucks! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH ExchangeCTE AS
(   SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY source_currency_code, target_currency_code ORDER BY date_loaded DESC) [RowNum]
    FROM    texchange_rate
)
SELECT  a.source_currency_code, 
        a.target_currency_code,
        a.entry_no AS entry_no,
        '(' + a.source_currency_code + ') '  + s.currency_name AS source_currency_name, 
        '(' + a.target_currency_code + ') '  + t.currency_name AS target_currency_name,
        a.value_amount AS value_amount,
        a.uplift_percent AS uplift,
        a.date_loaded AS date_loaded2,
        b.value_amount AS Previous_Value_Amount,
        CASE WHEN a.value_amount > b.value_amount THEN '^'
            WHEN a.value_amount = b.value_amount THEN '<->'
            ELSE 'v'
        END AS [Symbol]
FROM    ExchangeCTE a
        INNER JOIN ExchangeCTE b
            ON a.source_currency_code = b.source_currency_code 
            AND a.target_currency_code = b.target_currency_code
            AND a.RowNum = b.RowNum - 1 -- PREVIOUS RECORD
        INNER JOIN tcurrency s
            ON a.source_currency_code = S.currency_code 
        INNER JOIN tcurrency t
            ON a.target_currency_code = S.currency_code  
WHERE   a.RowNum = 1 -- LATEST RECORD
```

It is not necessary to have the `WHERE a.RowNum = 1`, Without this it will just return all records with their previous value next to them.